# Can you make a program create variables in python?

Tags: python, variables

I'm french so my formulation might seem weird.
I was wondering if a program could create variables that it could then use later in the same program.
For example, I can input a string with the value "Var1" and a variable called Var1 will then be created. If it can be done, I would really like to know how.

I had this idea where you could maybe throw the variable names in another text file that you would relaod as variables but I'm not sure it would work and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You could use a dictionary: `dict = {}; dict["Var1"] = "something"`